# Is anyone here going to the ReMIX South 2012 Conference?

Tags: discussion, site-growth

Are any users already planning on attending **[ReMIX South 2012](http://remixsouth.com/index.html)** in Atlanta, October 19-20? SE would love to send some items for these users to wear and/or give away if possible.

If you're attending the conference, and you'd be interested in helping promote UX.SE, please answer this meta post with which dates you plan to be at the conference, as well as which talks/panels you plan on attending.

**Note:** If you'd like to be sponsored to attend the conference, please see this post: [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/)